# Angular 4 - *ngFor with condition to get different value for ngModel

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm a newbie in angular 4.
I'm facing a problem with ***ngFor** with HTML drop-down **select and option**.

I have categories array-object -

```
categories = [
{ id:1, title: 'c/c++'},
{ id:2, title: 'JavaScript'},
{ id:3, title: 'Angular'},
{ id:4, title: 'Node'}
];
```

I want to show title in the dropdown but I want to get the category id in the ngModel.

Like - in HTML view show all title in a dropdown list, but when I select one of them then ngModel will get that category id.

**i.e: I select JavaScript, ngModel will get the id of JavaScript category.**

I search much time on google but I could not find any solution.

Here is HTML code -

```
  <label>Category</label>
  <select [(ngModel)]="post.category_id" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
      <option  *ngFor="let category of categories">{{ category.title}}</option>
   </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the `value` property:

```
<option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category.id">{{ category.title }}</option>
```

Comment: could you explain to me how it works? actually, I want to know about ngFor full cycle how its work.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to update `ngModel` variable and `option` as below.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="category_id" class="form-control select2">
   <option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category.id" 
           [innerHtml]=" category.title "></option>
</select>
```

In your code `post.category_id` `post` will get the value of id and then `post.category_id` will give `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

After various tries able to find out the mistake you are making.....
Please check the following points first

- First of all to include the ngModel directive you have to import the following in your app.ts:

```js
 import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

- After importing these your @NgModule must look like this

```js
    @NgModule({

  imports: [ BrowserModule,FormsModule,
    HttpModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
  })
```

- After this try this code to check for the desired result

```html
 <label>Category</label>
      <select [(ngModel)]="category_id" name="category_id" class="form-control select2" style="width:100%">
      <option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category.id">{{ category.title }}</option>
      </select>
      <h2>Select Category Id : {{category_id}}</h2>
```

You must get your desired result after these steps